# Distance making $(\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z},d) $ complete and homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

As in the title I have to construct a metric $d$ on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $( \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}, d)$ is complete and homeomorphic to $ \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Z}$.

I don't know how to proceed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Z} = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} (n, n+1)$$

Now make sure that points in $(n,n+1)$ have their usual distance among each other (so that is a homeomorphic copy of $\mathbb{R}$) but points in different $(n,n+1)$ and $(m,m+1)$ (so $n \neq m$) are very far apart from each other. Then we get a so-called sum space of countably many copies of the  reals, which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Z}$.

To get a complete metric replace the usual metric on $(n,n+1)$ with $|h(x) -h(y)|$ where $h$ is any homeomorphism between this interval and $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If you put the usual distance on $(n,n+1)$ you get non-convergent Cauchy sequences.

Comment: I thaught a distance like $|x-y| + | \frac{1}{dist(x,\mathbb{Z})} - \frac{1}{dist(y,\mathbb{Z})} | $...

Comment: @Christoph I made a remark on that too.

Comment: @Bremen000 can you show the homeomorphism with that metric?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma no, I wasn't able!